# How can I find a song that was sent to me in WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp

I have downloaded a song sent by my friend in WhatsApp. But there is no trace of that song either in my sd card or in my phone memory! I can only hear that song if I open it from WhatsApp. How do I find that song in my phone memory or my sd card?

Comment: I want to open the song from my files not from WhatsApp!

Comment: Read the other answer, please!

Comment: I think in next version the facility will be made available.

Comment: @vembutech Source?